TypeORM. Find where every field of the many-to-many relation is present in array
My goal is to find a chat where the field members includes every one of the IDs (basically an array of IDs) I'm getting from the frontend. The problem is that members is a many-to-many relation. In this case, I need to check the field called members.firebaseId. But how can I create a query to go through each of these relations, find if firebaseId is in the array of IDs, and if only one similar ID is found (but there are 2 users in the chat), then return nothing?
I tried to use IN, but obviously it's not going to work because if it finds at least 1 ID, it immediately returns the result (but as I mentioned, I need to find a chat where EVERY one of the IDs is in members.firebaseId).
// Chat.ts
@Entity()
export class Chat implements IChat {
  @PrimaryColumn("text")
  id: string

  @ManyToMany(() => User, (user) => user.chats)
  @JoinTable()
  members: User[]

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (message) => message.chat)
  messages: Message[]

  constructor() {
    this.id = nanoid(8)
  }
}

// User.ts
@Entity()
export class User implements IUser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column("text")
  firebaseId: string

  @Column("text")
  displayName: string

  @Column("text")
  email: string

  @Column("text")
  photoURL: string

  @Column("boolean")
  online: boolean

  @OneToMany(() => Message, (message) => message.author)
  messages: Message[]

  @ManyToMany(() => Chat, (chat) => chat.members)
  chats: Chat[]

  constructor(firebaseId: string, displayName: string, email: string, photoURL: string, online = false) {
    this.firebaseId = firebaseId
    this.displayName = displayName
    this.email = email
    this.photoURL = photoURL
    this.online = online
  }
}

The approach I was trying doesn't work correctly:
const chatExists = await chatRepository.findOne({
        relations: ["members", "messages"],
        where: {
          members: {
            firebaseId: In(members),
          },
        },
      })

